# Windows Mobile Custom Dialog for Web Application?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, mobile, mobile-website

Have already posted this on MSDN Windows Developer forum - no responses yet.

I am working on a Project porting a client's Java/JavaScript mobile non-native application from  Windows CE to Windows Mobile 6.5.  OpenModalWindow does not work on WM - the application freezes up when it hits this statement.  Searching for a way to display similar popup error messages to the user.  Solution must allow customizable text for the command buttons (like OpenModalWindow) as there is a requirement to retain existing globalization functionality (displays command button text in different languages depending on where the handheld application is being used).

On Windows CE, warning messages to the user were originally displayed using the OpenModalWindow and passing in the message button text from a resource file to achieve globalization (displays the command button text in different languages depending on the location where the handheld device is being used):

```
 windowRef.openModalWindow(errorWindowTitle,validationWindowURL,163,127,450,325,false,dialogArgs);
```

The OpenModalWindow function does NOT work on Windows Mobile 6.5.  The application freezes up when it hits this statement (have to kill the process or warm boot the device to stop it).

The Javascript functions confirm(), prompt() and alert() work fine but not an option for us because the text of the command buttons is not customizable.  Found an old post on MSDN that describes how to customize which command buttons that display on a confirm() message box.  Very cool, but we need customizable text on the buttons...

We have tried using SimpleModel from the JQuery UI Dialog plug-in, but both the WCE device and the WM device ignore the statement (nothing happens when it executes).    http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/dialog

Does anyone out there know why OpenModalWindow does not work on the WM platform and if there is a fix for this?
If not, do you know of a standard function that provides the same functionality on WM??

Trying to avoid having to do a major rewrite of the web application just to develop a workaround for OpenModalWindow not working...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jQuery works properly on windows mobile 6, you hardly get Ajax working on pocket ie.